# in python: child processes going defunct while others are not, unsure why

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

edit: the answer was that the os was axing processes because i was consuming all the memory

i am spawning enough subprocesses to keep the load average 1:1 with cores, however at some point within the hour, this script could run for days, 3 of the processes go :

```
tipu   14804  0.0  0.0 328776   428 pts/1    Sl   00:20   0:00 python run.py
tipu   14808 64.4 24.1 2163796 1848156 pts/1 Rl   00:20  44:41 python run.py
tipu   14809  8.2  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z    00:20   5:43 [python] <defunct>
tipu   14810 60.3 24.3 2180308 1864664 pts/1 Rl   00:20  41:49 python run.py
tipu   14811 20.2  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z    00:20  14:04 [python] <defunct>
tipu   14812 22.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z    00:20  15:18 [python] <defunct>
tipu   15358  0.0  0.0 103292   872 pts/1    S+   01:30   0:00 grep python
```

i have no idea why this is happening, attached is the master and slave. i can attach the mysql/pg wrappers if needed as well, any suggestions?

`slave.py`:

```
from boto.s3.key import Key
import multiprocessing
import gzip
import os
from  mysql_wrapper import MySQLWrap
from pgsql_wrapper import PGSQLWrap
import boto
import re

class Slave:

    CHUNKS = 250000

    BUCKET_NAME = "bucket"
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY = ""
    AWS_ACCESS_SECRET = ""
    KEY = Key(boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_SECRET).get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME))
    S3_ROOT = "redshift_data_imports"
    COLUMN_CACHE = {}
    DEFAULT_COLUMN_VALUES = {}

    def __init__(self, job_queue):
        self.log_handler = open("logs/%s" % str(multiprocessing.current_process().name), "a");
        self.mysql = MySQLWrap(self.log_handler)
        self.pg = PGSQLWrap(self.log_handler)
        self.job_queue = job_queue


    def do_work(self):
        self.log(str(os.getpid()))
        while True:

            #sample job in the abstract: mysql_db.table_with_date-iteration
            job = self.job_queue.get()

            #queue is empty
            if job is None:
                self.log_handler.close()
                self.pg.close()
                self.mysql.close()
                print("good bye and good day from %d" % (os.getpid()))
                self.job_queue.task_done()
                break

            #curtail iteration
            table = job.split('-')[0]

            #strip redshift table from job name
            redshift_table = re.sub(r"(_[1-9].*)", "", table.split(".")[1])

            iteration = int(job.split("-")[1])
            offset = (iteration - 1) * self.CHUNKS

            #columns redshift is expecting
            #bad tables will slip through and error out, so we catch it
            try:
                colnames = self.COLUMN_CACHE[redshift_table]
            except KeyError:
                self.job_queue.task_done()
                continue

            #mysql fields to use in SELECT statement
            fields = self.get_fields(table)

            #list subtraction determining which columns redshift has that mysql does not
            delta = (list(set(colnames) - set(fields.keys())))

            #subtract columns that have a default value and so do not need padding
            if delta:
                delta = list(set(delta) - set(self.DEFAULT_COLUMN_VALUES[redshift_table]))

            #concatinate columns with padded \N
            select_fields = ",".join(fields.values()) + (",\\N" * len(delta))

            query = "SELECT %s FROM %s LIMIT %d, %d" % (select_fields, table,
                    offset, self.CHUNKS)

            rows = self.mysql.execute(query)

            self.log("%s: %s\n" % (table, len(rows)))

            if not rows:
                self.job_queue.task_done()
                continue

            #if there is more data potentially, add it to the queue
            if len(rows) == self.CHUNKS:
                self.log("putting %s-%s" % (table, (iteration+1)))
                self.job_queue.put("%s-%s" % (table, (iteration+1)))

            #various characters need escaping
            clean_rows = []
            redshift_escape_chars = set( ["\\", "|", "\t", "\r", "\n"] )
            in_chars = ""

            for row in rows:
                new_row = []
                for value in row:
                    if value is not None:
                        in_chars = str(value)
                    else:
                        in_chars = ""

                    #escape any naughty characters
                    new_row.append("".join(["\\" + c if c in redshift_escape_chars else c for c in in_chars]))
                new_row = "\t".join(new_row)
                clean_rows.append(new_row)

            rows = ",".join(fields.keys() + delta)
            rows += "\n" + "\n".join(clean_rows)

            offset = offset + self.CHUNKS

            filename = "%s-%s.gz" % (table, iteration) 
            self.move_file_to_s3(filename, rows)

            self.begin_data_import(job, redshift_table, ",".join(fields.keys() +
               delta))

            self.job_queue.task_done()


    def move_file_to_s3(self, uri, contents):

        tmp_file = "/dev/shm/%s" % str(os.getpid())

        self.KEY.key = "%s/%s" % (self.S3_ROOT, uri)
        self.log("key is %s" % self.KEY.key )

        f = gzip.open(tmp_file, "wb")
        f.write(contents)
        f.close()

        #local saving allows for debugging when copy commands fail
        #text_file = open("tsv/%s" % uri, "w")
        #text_file.write(contents)
        #text_file.close()

        self.KEY.set_contents_from_filename(tmp_file, replace=True)

    def get_fields(self, table):
        """
            Returns a dict used as: 
                {"column_name": "altered_column_name"}
            Currently only the debug column gets altered
        """
        exclude_fields = ["_qproc_id", "_mob_id", "_gw_id", "_batch_id", "Field"]

        query = "show columns from %s" % (table)
        fields = self.mysql.execute(query)

        #key raw field, value mysql formatted field
        new_fields = {}

        #for field in fields:
        for field in [val[0] for val in fields]:
            if field in exclude_fields:
                continue
            old_field = field

            if "debug_mode" == field.strip():
                field = "IFNULL(debug_mode, 0)"

            new_fields[old_field] = field

        return new_fields

    def log(self, text):
        self.log_handler.write("\n%s" % text)

    def begin_data_import(self, table, redshift_table, fields):
        query = "copy %s (%s) from 's3://bucket/redshift_data_imports/%s' \
            credentials 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s' delimiter '\\t' \
            gzip NULL AS '' COMPUPDATE ON ESCAPE IGNOREHEADER 1;" \
            % (redshift_table, fields, table, self.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, self.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET)
        self.pg.execute(query)
```

`master.py`:

```
from slave import Slave as Slave 
import multiprocessing
from mysql_wrapper import MySQLWrap as MySQLWrap
from pgsql_wrapper import PGSQLWrap as PGSQLWrap


class Master:

    SLAVE_COUNT = 5

    def __init__(self):
        self.mysql = MySQLWrap()
        self.pg = PGSQLWrap()

    def do_work(table):
        pass

    def get_table_listings(self):
        """Gathers a list of MySQL log tables needed to be imported"""

        query = 'show databases'
        result = self.mysql.execute(query)

        #turns list[tuple] into a flat list
        databases = list(sum(result, ()))

        #overriding during development
        databases = ['db1', 'db2', 'db3']]

        exclude = ('mysql', 'Database', 'information_schema')
        scannable_tables = []

        for database in databases:
            if database in exclude:
                continue

            query = "show tables from %s" % database
            result = self.mysql.execute(query)

            #turns list[tuple] into a flat list
            tables = list(sum(result, ()))

            for table in tables:
                exclude = ("Tables_in_%s" % database, "(", "201303", "detailed", "ltv")

                #exclude any of the unfavorables
                if any(s in table for s in exclude):
                    continue

                scannable_tables.append("%s.%s-1" % (database, table))

        return scannable_tables

    def init(self):
        #fetch redshift columns once and cache
        #get columns from redshift so we can pad the mysql column delta with nulls
        tables = ('table1', 'table2', 'table3')

        for table in tables:

            #cache columns
            query = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE \
            table_name = '%s'" % (table)
            result = self.pg.execute(query, async=False, ret=True)
            Slave.COLUMN_CACHE[table] = list(sum(result, ()))

            #cache default values
            query = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE \
            table_name = '%s' and column_default is not \
            null" % (table)

            result = self.pg.execute(query, async=False, ret=True)

            #turns list[tuple] into a flat list
            result = list(sum(result, ()))

            Slave.DEFAULT_COLUMN_VALUES[table] = result

    def run(self):
        self.init()

        job_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        tables = self.get_table_listings()
        for table in tables:
            job_queue.put(table)

        processes = []
        for i in range(Master.SLAVE_COUNT):
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=slave_runner, args=(job_queue,))
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()
            processes.append(process)

        #blocks this process until queue reaches 0
        job_queue.join()

        #signal each child process to GTFO
        for i in range(Master.SLAVE_COUNT):
            job_queue.put(None)

        #blocks this process until queue reaches 0
        job_queue.join()

        job_queue.close()

        #do not end this process until child processes close out
        for process in processes:
            process.join()

        #toodles !
        print("this is master saying goodbye")


def slave_runner(queue):
    slave = Slave(queue)
    slave.do_work()
```

Comment: Have you looked at the logs or the stdout or stderr? In particular, are the children quitting because of an unhandled exception? (If you use `multiprocessing.Pool`, that's taken care of for you. If you build one yourself, you have to write the code to take care of it.)

Comment: For that matter… it looks like you're trying to build almost _exactly_ the same thing as `Pool`. Why not just use `Pool` instead? (You could then simplify and/or optimize things even further by using one of the `map`-family methods on the `Pool` over `tables`.)

Comment: @abarnert because the workload isn't generated once in the beginning, it is dynamically expanded upon on a per table basis.

Comment: So? You can keep submitting new jobs to a `Pool` after it's created. Including doing so from within the children. They even show this in the examples.

Comment: i am rechecking the documents, can you link me to the relevant portion please @abamert?

Comment: OK, looking again… they don't have an example with that. I must have seen the example in a tutorial somewhere. I could write one up for you, or google it, if you need it?

Comment: a quick write up/googled tutorial would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @nneonneo: Are you sure you fixed the indentation right? I'm pretty think that  was two separate files, and the only problem was that he wrote `class Master` instead of `file Slave.py` and `class Slave` instead of `file Master.py` (mixing up the two). The way it is now, it doesn't make any sense, and couldn't possibly run.

Comment: OK, I've added some more to my answer. But first, you may want to look at the logs/stdout/stderr, log more if necessary, try the "duct-tape fix" from my answer, etc. to make sure this really is your problem, and you really do have a working answer you could (if necessary) implement right now.

Comment: @abarnert: My bad. Fixed, I think. tipu should check it over.

Comment: trying to log more, i've wrapped the entire while True: loop around in a try except and it defuncted with no output to my logs. being verbose with my output/logging and trying again.

Comment: @tipu: OK, the first thing you have to figure out is why the child processes are exiting. The only obvious way you can exit the loop will cause you to print "goodbye and good day", so if that isn't happening, something non-obvious is. A few more things you can try: handle `BaseException`, or even a bare `except`. Or stick a `try`/`finally` around the whole method. Or install an `atexit` handler. Even install handlers for every possible `signal`.

Comment: @tipu: Meanwhile, if you _do_ discover something, hopefully it's something that's easy to fix or work around (like the unhandled `Exception` from my first guess). But if not, you may need to fire up new processes if old ones die, or at least notice and mark the broken queue so you can deal with it at a higher level (see the source to `ProcessPoolExecutor` that I linked to for an example of that—although it's built around `concurrent.futures.wait`, so some of the details are hidden a level down).

Comment: our ops guy has informed me that i was using near max levels of memory, and that the server was axing the most offensive processes to free some up, which happened to be what i was doing. whoops. the second time around, i am not seeing any defunct processes when i regularly would have.

Comment: @tipu: That makes sense, and it may be hard or impossible to detect from in-process in the children. But… does it really not log anything to syslog when that happens?

Comment: i am unsure if it does, and if it did i wouldn't know where to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not enough information to be sure, but the problem is very likely to be that `Slave.do_work` is raising an unhandled exception. (There are many lines of your code that could do that in various different conditions.)

When you do that, the child process will just exit.

On POSIX systems… well, the full details are a bit complicated, but in the simple case (what you have here), a child process that exits will stick around as a `<defunct>` process until it gets reaped (because the parent either `wait`s on it, or exits). Since your parent code doesn't wait on the children until the queue is finished, that's exactly what happens.

So, there's a simple duct-tape fix:

```
def do_work(self):
    self.log(str(os.getpid()))
    while True:
        try:
            # the rest of your code
        except Exception as e:
            self.log("something appropriate {}".format(e))
            # you may also want to post a reply back to the parent
```

You might also want to break the massive `try` up into different ones, so you can distinguish between all the different stages where things could go wrong (especially if some of them mean you need a reply, and some mean you don't).

---

However, it looks like what you're attempting to do is duplicate exactly the behavior of `multiprocessing.Pool`, but have missed the bar in a couple places. Which raises the question: why not just use `Pool` in the first place? You could then simplify/optimize things ever further by using one of the `map` family methods. For example, your entire `Master.run` could be reduced to:

```
self.init()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(Master.SLAVE_COUNT, initializer=slave_setup)
pool.map(slave_job, tables)
pool.join()
```

And this will handle exceptions for you, and allow you to return values/exceptions if you later need that, and let you use the built-in `logging` library instead of trying to build your own, and so on. And it should only take about a dozens lines of minor code changes to `Slave`, and then you're done.

---

If you want to submit new jobs from within jobs, the easiest way to do this is probably with a [`Future`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects)-based API (which turns things around, making the future result the focus and the pool/executor the dumb thing that provides them, instead of making the pool the focus and the result the dumb thing it gives back), but there are multiple ways to do it with `Pool` as well. For example, right now, you're not returning anything from each job, so, you can just return a list of `tables` to execute. Here's a simple example that shows how to do it:

```
import multiprocessing

def foo(x):
    print(x, x**2)
    return list(range(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    jobs = [5]
    while jobs:
        jobs, oldjobs = [], jobs
        for job in oldjobs:
            jobs.extend(pool.apply(foo, [job]))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Obviously you can condense this a bit by replacing the whole loop with, e.g., a list comprehension fed into `itertools.chain`, and you can make it a lot cleaner-looking by passing "a submitter" object to each job and adding to that instead of returning a list of new jobs, and so on. But I wanted to make it as explicit as possible to show how little there is to it.

---

At any rate, if you think the explicit queue is easier to understand and manage, go for it. Just look at the source for [`multiprocessing.worker`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/65e8ac5f073f/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l66) and/or [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#l318) to see what you need to do yourself. It's not that hard, but there are enough things you could get wrong (personally, I always forget at least one edge case when I try to do something like this myself) that it's work looking at code that gets it right.

---

Alternatively, it seems like the only reason you can't use [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) here is that you need to initialize some per-process state (the `boto.s3.key.Key`, `MySqlWrap`, etc.), for what are probably very good caching reasons. (If this involves a web-service query, a database connect, etc., you certainly don't want to do that once per task!) But there are a few different ways around that.

But you can subclass `ProcessPoolExecutor` and override the undocumented function `_adjust_process_count` (see [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#l376) for how simple it is) to pass your setup function, and… that's all you have to do.

Or you can mix and match. Wrap the `Future` from `concurrent.futures` around the `AsyncResult` from `multiprocessing`.

Comment: can i dynamically add jobs to the workers after the pool.map call within the workers themselves?

Comment: @tipu: Yes. You just have to give the workers—or, more simply, the jobs themselves—a reference to the pool. Or you can have each job just return a list of new tables to submit, and chain things together in the parent. Or… This part is a lot simpler with `concurrent.futures.Executor` than with `multiprocessing.Pool`—but, unfortunately, that module doesn't give you any way to do to per-worker setup to create stateful things like your MySqlWrap once per process. But you can still borrow its `Future` class and wrap it around your jobs manually.

Comment: Sorry, you can't give them a _direct_ reference to the pool; the sample code I was looking at actually passed a pool-submitter object around, which… really isn't any cleaner than the explicit queue. But that's not the only way to do things. So, I expanded my answer to give options.